# javascript: print websocket client IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

## node.js WebSocket example code snippet

I have a simple node.js application using express. **Now everytime a client connects to the node server I see the string 'new client connected' but I would like to know which IP the new client had.**

```js
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var connIds = [];

var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(80);

// set up the websocket server
var wss = new WebSocketServer( { server: server } );
wss.clientConnections = {};

// websocket server eventlisteners and callbacks
wss.on('connection', function (connection) {
  console.log('wss.on.connection - new client connected');
  ...
```

See the code at:
https://github.com/qknight/relais.js/blob/master/relais.js/server.js#L159

## question

The object `connection` has properties but I don't understand how to query them or what they are. **All I want is to print the client IP and maybe, if existent, other similar properties as well.**

How do I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remote IP is a property of the pre-upgrade connection:

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9876});    

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log(ws.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress);
});
```

i don't recall how i found it, but i know it took me a while; i wish the docs were as good as the code...

UPDATE:
WS has moved some things around, so here's an updated example of how to get the original HTTP info in current code. Note the 2nd argument to the connection event handler:

```
wss.on('connection', function conn(ws, req) {
    var ip  =  req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.info(ip);
});
```

Comment: it just gives me an IP address of server, not the client.

Comment: @JurajCarnogursky you probably get IP of server because your proxy doesn't forward the client IP in header. You need to check the proxy settings.

Comment: @SeanNovak: yeah, this is like 5 years old and WS changed a lot. I can post the new code if you like, i just re-fixed this last week by coincidence...

Comment: @dandavis, That would be great.  I wouldn't have thought the client IP would be so obscure.